# render the table on modal in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am facing issue of table not being rendered on twitter bootstrap modal. I am doing similar to mentioned in the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/iamakshay04/sh26m80o/2/) . So to test it, I tried exactly same mentioned and found that data(table) is rendered on the page instead of the modal.

```
<div id="classModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" 
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classInfo" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
          ×
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="classModalLabel">
          Class Info
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CLN</td>
              <td>Last Updated Date</td>
              <td>Class Name</td>
              <td># Tests</td>
              <td>Test Coverage (Instruction)</td>
              <td>Test Coverage (Complexity)</td>
              <td>Complex Covered</td>
              <td>Complex Total</td>
              <td>Category</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#classModal').modal('show')
```

CSS:

```
#classModal {}

.modal-body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem here. In the example you link to, the table appears to show up just fine in the modal body. What are you expecting?

Comment: @JonahBishop, I am expecting it to work as mentioned in the example http://jsfiddle.net/iamakshay04/sh26m80o/2/, but when i put the same code, the result is different. what i mean is table is rendered but not on the modal.